# Can SharePoint Framework (SPFX) be used to create projects outside SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, spfx, sharepointframework

Can I use SPFX for development of projects which will be used outside of SharePoint environment.

For Example:

- A standalone calculator for Windows.
- Something similar to music player for any operating system.
- photo editing app for any OS.
- A website similar to trello.
- Extensions for any browser.

Can any type of development be done using SPFX or it's just SharePoint related development?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Framework was developed to provide flexibility of modern web features, which enables developers to provide optimal solutions and incredible UI with the cutting-edge technologies like **Angular** and **React**.

However, there are some limitations. The wide variety of tech stack is just for web development - a SharePoint WebPart or a Feature.

Strictly speaking, "the code build in **SPFx** would need **SharePoint environment** to work. **SPFx** was never meant to be a global platform to develop native apps or browser extensions".

Although ***JavaScript*** is a language that can help you achieve those tasks.

- **Electron** - for Desktop application development
- **React Native** - for Mobile application development (iOS or Android)
- **Ember** - for Chrome extension development

Hope this information helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's just SharePoint related development. You could read this article for more:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview

> The SharePoint Framework (SPFx) is a page and web part model that
>   provides full support for client-side SharePoint development, easy
>   integration with SharePoint data, and support for open source tooling.
>   With the SharePoint Framework, you can use modern web technologies and
>   tools in your preferred development environment to build productive
>   experiences and apps that are responsive and mobile-ready from day
>   one. The SharePoint Framework works for SharePoint Online and also for
>   on-premises (SharePoint 2016 Feature Pack 2 and SharePoint 2019).